# How to get Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ for $x_0 = \pi/4$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to get the series said above. The problem is that I found a sequence that follows a weird pattern. Follow my solution below:

$$ f(x) = \sin(x);$$
$$x_0 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Theory to develop Taylor series: Be $S(x)$ the Taylor Series that represent $f(x)$ develop around $x_0$. So, we have:

$$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$

Replacing variables, we have:

$$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{n}(\frac{\pi}{4})}{n!}(x-\frac{\pi}{4})^n$$

Getting all derivative patterns:

$$f^{(4k)}(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$f^{(4k+1)}(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \cos{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$f^{(4k+2)}(\frac{\pi}{4}) = - \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}} = - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$f^{(4k+3)}(\frac{\pi}{4}) = - \cos{\frac{\pi}{4}} = - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$\forall \; k \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}$$

I don't know what pattern matches this one to build the series. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Double check the derivatives, there's a mistake (I suggest you first write them as functions and the plug the value $x=\pi/4$).

Comment: Alternatively, expand the Taylor series at $h_0=0$ of $\sin(\pi/4+h)=(\cos h+\sin h)/\sqrt2.$

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt, I really made a mistake. I'll edit the question here but still don't know how to proceed to the solution.

Comment: @AnneBauval I can't expand the series for $x_0 = 0$. The point of the exercise is to build a taylor series using the definition to build a serie for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Yes you can. The point of the exercise is to build the series of $\sin$ **around $\pi/4$**, but the series of $\sin$ and $\cos$ **around $0$** are "common knowledge" (or at worst, can be re-computed beforehand).

Comment: I would go for splitting the series into even-indexed terms and odd-indexed terms.

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry but still I don't got your point. If I have a taylor series for $\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ I have only odd coeficients because they are oscillant like $(-1)^{n}$. The even coeffients are 0. How can I use this to build around $x_0 = \frac{\pi}{4}$ as the derivative pattern gets diferent values as shown in the statement?

Comment: You don't need the derivatives. Simply combine the series around $0$ of $\cos$ and $\sin,$ by the change of variable indicated in my 1st comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks, I found this solution: $\sin(\pi/4 + x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{n!} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ with $x_0 = \frac{\pi}{4}$. But one thing, how do you know this relation $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + h) = \cos(h) + \sin(h)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + h) =\color{red}(\cos h+ \sin h\color{red})/\sqrt2$ is an instance of $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b.$ And the solution of your last comment is not correct. For instance the first terms of  $\cos x+\sin x$ are $1\color{red}+x\color{red}-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}6,$ not $1-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}6.$